# How to sort values of a field in a structure in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, sorting, structure

In my code, I have a structure and in a field of it, I want to sort its values. 
For instance, in the field of `File_Neg.name` there are the following values, and They should be sorted as the right values.

```
File_Neg.name        --> Sorted File_Neg.name
'-10.000000.dcm'         '-10.000000.dcm'
'-102.500000.dcm'        '-12.500000.dcm'
'-100.000000.dcm'        '-100.000000.dcm' 
'-107.500000.dcm'        '-102.500000.dcm'  
'-112.500000.dcm'        '-107.500000.dcm'
'-110.000000.dcm         '-110.000000.dcm' 
'-12.500000.dcm'         '-112.500000.dcm'
```

There is a folder that there are some pictures with negative labels in it (above example are labels of pictures). I want to get them in the same order as present in the folder(that's mean the `Sorted File_Neg.name`). But when running the following code the values of `Files_Neg.name` load as the above example (left: `File_Neg.name`), while I want the right form.
I have also seen [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/52414-how-to-sort-a-structure-by-numbers-in-one-of-its-fields) and [that](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97965-how-can-i-sort-an-array-of-structures-based-upon-a-particular-field-in-matlab) but they didn't help me.
How to sort values of a field in a structure in Matlab?

```
Files_Neg = dir('D:\Rename-RealN'); 
File_Neg = dir(strcat('D:\Rename-RealN\', Files_Neg.name, '\', '*.dcm'));  
% when running the code the values of Files_Neg.name load as the above example (left: File_Neg.name)
```

`File_Neg.name`:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what is meant by "sort values of a field in a structure". You could create a new variable with the values of said field, remove the field from the structure, sort the independent variable and then re-add the field as being equal to the sorted variable. Would that solve your problem? Note that the dir command returns a n-by-1 structure array, so maybe you want to actually sort a vector of structs based on a given field.

Comment: @Mefitico: The meaning of field is the above figure (Files_Neg.name),  when running the code, it returns a structure with an unordered list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97965-how-can-i-sort-an-array-of-structures-based-upon-a-particular-field-in-matlab#answer_251023) to one of the questions linked in the OP is nearly correct for the problem in the OP. There are two issues:

The first issue is that the answer assumes a scalar value is contained in the field to be sorted, whereas in the OP the values are char arrays (i.e. old-fashioned strings).

This issue can be fixed by adding `'UniformOutput',false` to the `arrayfun` call:

```
File_Neg = struct('name',{'-10.000000.dcm','-102.500000.dcm','-100.000000.dcm','-107.500000.dcm','-112.500000.dcm','-110.000000.dcm','-12.500000.dcm'},...
                  'folder',{'a','b','c','d','e1','e2','e3'});

[~,I] = sort(arrayfun(@(x)x.name,File_Neg,'UniformOutput',false));
File_Neg = File_Neg(I);
```

`File_Neg` is now sorted according to dictionary sort (using ASCII letter ordering, meaning that uppercase letters come first, and 110 still comes before 12).

The second issue is that OP wants to sort according to the magnitude of the number in the file name, not using dictionary sort. This can be fixed by extracting the value in the anonymous function applied using `arrayfun`. We use `str2double` on the file name, minus the last 4 characters `'.dcm'`:

```
[~,I] = sort(arrayfun(@(x)abs(str2double(x.name(1:end-4))),File_Neg));
File_Neg = File_Neg(I);
```

Funnily enough, we don't want to use `'UniformOutput',false` any more, since the anonymous function now returns a scalar value.

Comment: like my previous question....., How to use absolute (abs) in the following code in python? Also, `dcmfiles` is a list of values like `Files_Neg.name`. => `dcmFilesList = sorted(dcmfiles, key=lambda x: float(x[:-4]), reverse=True)` ---> The output isn't correct : `dcmFilesList = sorted(dcmfiles, key=lambda x: abs(float(x[:-4])), reverse=True)`

Comment: @eli: I don’t know Python all that well, you might want to create a new question for that.